# Angular 4 - Remove value from array when unchecked checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I remove the value from array when I uncheck the checkbox?

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="saveUserNameCheckBox" (change)="selChk(member.id)"  [checked]="false">
```

**component**

```
selChk(val) {

   if (this.id.indexOf(val) == -1) {
    this.id.push(val);
    console.log(this.id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already found the index why not just use `splice`?

```
selChk(val) {
 var index = this.id.indexOf(val);
 if(index === -1){
   // val not found, pushing onto array
   this.id.push(val);
 }else{
   // val is found, removing from array
   this.id.splice(index,1);
 }
}
```

Comment: @SagarAhuja See the comments above. If you are using a checkbox to determine inclusion of a val in a array this would be a solution to manage that.

Comment: I have added the below which explains things more better please accept it if you feel its helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML :

```
<input (change)="onCheckUser(user.user_id,$event)" type="checkbox">
```

In your Ts:

```
Follow_list = []; // Variable Declared 


onCheckUser(Id, event) {
  const checked = event.target.checked; // stored checked value true or false
   if (checked) {
     this.Follow_list.push({ user_id: Id }); // push the Id in array if checked
      } else {
      const index = this.Follow_list.findIndex(list => list.user_id == Id);//Find the index of stored id
      this.Follow_list.splice(index, 1); // Then remove
    }
 }
```